# Setting Textview inside Decoview

Tags: android, charts

I want add textview to show % inside decoview using linearlayout. How can I achieve this.https://i.stack.imgur.com/THZab.png

```
        <com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView
            android:id="@+id/dynamicarcview"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        </com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DecoView inside a constraint Layout. Then you can place a text view giving it the constraints as below:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_centerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="60%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dynamicarcview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/dynamicarcview"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dynamicarcview"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dynamicarcview"/>
```